# How to create a table with all the table names in my DB and for each one, the number of columns in the table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new at SQL developer so I don't really know a lot about it. 
I am trying to obtain (from a select) a table with the names of all the tables in my DB with its number of columns. I have tried to do it but, I can only count the number of columns for each table separately. I can't obtain the name of each table. 
Another problem that I found with my code, is that when I try to search in `ALL_TABLES`, it shows every table that I have access to, not only the ones in the DB that I need.

Try1:

```
SELECT COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
TABLE_CATALOG = 'database_name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

Comment: try to connect to system or sys schema(if you have access) to be able to query `all_tables` or `dba_tables` dictionary wiews to see the tables for overall DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job for you:

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COUNT(*) AS COLUMN_COUNT
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
  GROUP BY OWNER, TABLE_NAME
  ORDER BY OWNER, TABLE_NAME
```

You can also use the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` or `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` views if you have access to them.

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a7e86/3)

Comment: Bob, there's no `owner` column in `user_tab_columns`.

Comment: Good point. I switched `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` around in the answer and added [an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a7e86/3).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to consider `user_tables` in your query to remove recycled table names from your result.

Also note that `user_` views do not contain `OWNER` column. It is present in `all_` and `dba_` views.

```
select t.TABLE_NAME, COUNT(1) AS COLUMN_COUNT
from user_tab_cols tc
     join user_tables t
     on tc.table_name = t.table_name
where t.dropped = 'NO'
GROUP BY t.TABLE_NAME
```

Cheers!!